# how to make the background image in a canvas expand with the window?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am trying to set the background image of weather app I tried to use canvas for that but the image doesn't expand as the window and it expands only when I click search to see the results , the labels come out messy as although I used grid

can someone help me to fix this please

here is the code

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
root=tk.Tk()
root.minsize(width=1025, height=522)
def get_entry(*args):
    api_address='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weathe?appid=4f825a5771554e0c8fcccb7be76aab11&q='
    city=entry_1.get()
    url = api_address + city
    json_data = requests.get(url).json()
    format_add = json_data['weather'][0]['description']
    temp=json_data['main']['temp']
    press=json_data['main']['pressure']
    wind=json_data['wind']['speed']
```

displaying results through labels:

```
    label_2=tk.Label(canvas, text='the weather in '+city+' : '+format_add)
    label_3=tk.Label(canvas, text='the temperature :' +str(temp))
    label_4=tk.Label(canvas, text='the pressure:' +str(press))
    label_5=tk.Label(canvas, text='the wind speed:' +str(wind))
    label_2.grid(row=5,column=0,sticky='e',padx=20,pady=20)
    label_3.grid(row=6,column=0,sticky='e',padx=20,pady=20)
    label_4.grid(row=7,column=0,sticky='e',padx=20,pady=20)
    label_5.grid(row=8,column=0,sticky='e',padx=20,pady=20)
    Label = tk.Label(canvas, text =str(city), font = ('Comic Sans MS',30),
     fg = 'blue')
    Label.grid(row=4,column=630,sticky='n')
    rain_Frame=(root)
    rain_Frame.grid()
```

here is the code to set the background image

```
    background_image=Image.open('rain.jpg')
    canvas = tk.Canvas(rain_Frame, width=1025, height=522)
    canvas.grid()
    image1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(background_image)
    canvas.create_image(0,0, image=image1, anchor='center')
    label1=tk.Label(canvas,text='search by country/city')
    label1.grid(row=0,column=0)
    entry_1=tk.Entry(canvas)
    label_1.grid(row=0,column=0)
    entry_1.grid(row=0,column=20)
    search_button=tk.Button(canvas,text="search",
                      command=get_entry,
                width = 10, activebackground = "#33B5E5")

   search_button.grid(row=0,column=35,padx=10,pady=1,sticky='e')

   root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

   root.mainloop()
```

here is what the outcome looks like
 [Tkinter weather app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLH5s.png)

Comment: Please can you provide a **minimal**, **complete** and **verifiable** example according to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... why not use a bigger image? :D

Or stop the window resizing?

```
root = Tk()
root.resizable(0,0)
```

For the labels, you could use a grid... or you could just place them somewhere and leave them?

```
label.place(x=20, y=380)
```